# Change ZSH Command Prompt

Tags: zsh

[image][image]

I just recently changed to ZSH from bash and I see this weird command prompt.  I'd like to just have a simpler, shorter command prompt without all of this jargon.  Please assist...

Comment: please upload your ~/.zshrc so we could help you edit  .its look like you missing some fonts and also have `git` and `conda` plugins

Comment: @NaorTedgi, I added a screenshot of the ~/.zshrc file above.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: @AngeloBrown I suspect your `.bash_profile` has a lot of lines that are affecting ZSH. Could you take only the lines that you need from `.bash_profile` and copy them into `.zshrc`?

Comment: Don't use `.bash_profile` *at all* with `zsh`; `zsh` and `bash` are two entirely different shells. Learn to use `zsh` properly; start with `man zshmisc` to learn about its prompt escape sequences.

Comment: @Pierre, so I removed the source ~/.bash_profile line from the ~/.zshrc file.  Now how do I access all of the good stuff that I typically use such as Python, Anaconda, etc.  I guess what I'm trying to say is how do I add all of the stuff I need to the zshrc file so that I can run it from the command line.  For example, when I try to run conda, I get the zsh conda command not found...etc.

Comment: Problem solved!  Thank you to everyone who responded to this post!

Answer (score 0):

in macos, find your .zshrc file, open it in a text editor, locate the comment "#Default prompt", modify the line that looks like this:-- "PS1=%n@%m~%&# " (%n is your username; %m is the computer name), save the file (you will be prompted to enter your password to save it), load a new terminal to check out the changes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Alacritty and Oh-My-Zsh, I named my terminal in alacritty.yml as below:
`window:`
`title: Terminal Ihsan Praditya`
but nothing change, then I found a line in .zshrc, it's:
`# Uncomment the following line to disable auto-setting terminal title.`
`# DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"`
then I uncomment the line, restart the terminal, it's shown as below
[.zshrc after Oh-My-Zsh on Alacritty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eglzZ.png)